# What does LoadLibrary do if you give it the name of a DLL already statically linked to?

Tags: windows, dll, loadlibrary

On Windows, what will LoadLibrary do if you give it the name of a DLL that your executable already statically linked (aka implicitly linked) to? Will two copies of the DLL be loaded? What if the pathname of the DLL is some sort of alias for the original? For example, say I run the executable as `X:\myprog\myexe.exe`, and it implicitly links to X:\myprog\mydll.dll, but I pass LoadLibrary `\\the\unc\path\to\X\myprog\mydll.dll`. Is LoadLibrary smart enough to resolve these to the same DLL?

Comment: You'll get a reference to the already loaded module, and its reference count is incremented. You can also call `GetModuleHandle`, which will not increment the reference count. From experiment I see that a new module is loaded when I use "\\localhost\C$" instead of "C:"; however, a reference to the existing module is returned for a local symbolic link or hard link. For the link cases it's the same mapped file. For the UNC path, the redirector is proxying the remote file system, which happens to be local in this example. To the memory manager it looks like a separate file.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. Just curious - how come you didn't post this as an answer?

Comment: It looks like you'll also get a doubly-loaded module if you mix short names and long names: http://www.clausbrod.de/cgi-bin/view.pl/Blog/BlogOnSoftware20060107. This is something a colleague of mine is seeing too.